# How would i add very large Numbers represented as Strings i.e 50 digit numbers

Tags: java

Here in this program i have allready created a version using BigInterger but I'm stuck on making this version that only uses Strings. How would i go about adding two strings together which are very large, like 50 digit which uses just Strings. Thanks

```
public class BigStringNumber {

    int []f;
    String J;
public BigStringNumber(String H) {
    this.J=H;

    for(int i=0; i<H.length(); i++){
        f=new int[i];
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}   

public String toString(){ 

    return ""+J;
}

public BigStringNumber add(BigStringNumber d){


    return new BigStringNumber();
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    BigStringNumber A=new BigStringNumber("46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538");
    BigStringNumber a=new BigStringNumber("46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538");
    System.out.print(a.toString());
```

}

Comment: the add method there should have more in the return but would i use ValueOf or Stringbuffer?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel here? Just use `BigInteger`. Implementing `BigInteger` from scratch is going to be a lot of work, and before you start implementing `add` you'll need to fix your constructor to actually extract the digits...

Comment: Why yo not use java `BigInteger` class?

Comment: Hi i have allready done this on BigInteger and in i was asked to do this using strings?

Comment: @user3255780 `adding two strings together`? Concatenating the strings, or adding the values of integers inside the strings?

Comment: Take a look to `BigInteger` implementation - source code.

Comment: @admdrew value of the integers inside the strings since i cant parse them to a int or any other variable what would be the alternative?

Comment: If you want to operate with strings, you will need to write your own `add()` method, that will implement [`long addition`](http://www.thegreatmartinicompany.com/longarithmetic/long-arithmetic-home.html) (like in elementary school).

Answer (score 1):

It is not so hard to write the `add` method on your own.
This `add` does what students in 1st, 2nd, 3rd grades do.
Actually adults do the same for long numbers.

```
public class BigStringNumber {

    private int[] digit;
    // private String str;

    public BigStringNumber(String str) {
        // this.str = str;
        this.digit = new int[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            digit[i] = str.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<digit.length; i++){
            sb.append((char) ('0' + digit[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public BigStringNumber add(BigStringNumber d) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i1 = this.digit.length - 1;
        int i2 = d.digit.length - 1;
        int dgt = 0;
        int carry = 0;
        while (i1 >= 0 && i2 >= 0) {
            dgt = this.digit[i1] + d.digit[i2] + carry;
            carry = dgt / 10;
            dgt = dgt % 10;
            i1--;
            i2--;
            sb.append((char) ('0' + dgt));
        }
        while (i1 >= 0) {
            dgt = this.digit[i1] + carry;
            carry = dgt / 10;
            dgt = dgt % 10;
            i1--;
            sb.append((char) ('0' + dgt));
        }
        while (i2 >= 0) {
            dgt = d.digit[i2] + carry;
            carry = dgt / 10;
            dgt = dgt % 10;
            i2--;
            sb.append((char) ('0' + dgt));
        }
        sb = sb.reverse();
        return new BigStringNumber(sb.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigStringNumber a = new BigStringNumber("2020202029");
        BigStringNumber b = new BigStringNumber("4040404046");
        System.out.println(a.add(b).toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: one question can you help explain why i would use  i1--; & i2--;. thanks

Comment: You don't need to, but this is how digits are stored here. The most significant one is in position 0, the less significant one is in last position of the digits array. When you add you don't start from the most significant position.

Comment: sorry let me thank you first before asking you to clarify what you mean.sorry?

Comment: No, output is 6060606075 (with my example). You are running some old code of yours.

Comment: sorry but i dont want to copy code i dont undertand can you comment your code so it will be more helpfull

Comment: Debug it and you will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the Code to do this:

```
public class BigStringNumber {

    private int[] digit;
    // private String str;

    public BigStringNumber(String str) {
        // this.str = str;
        this.digit = new int[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            digit[i] = str.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<digit.length; i++){
            sb.append((char) ('0' + digit[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public BigStringNumber add(BigStringNumber d) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i1 = this.digit.length - 1;//contains first number
        int i2 = d.digit.length - 1;//second number
        int carry = 0;//variable
        int dgt = 0;//variable
        while (i1 >= 0 && i2 >= 0) {
            carry = this.digit[i1] + d.digit[i2] + dgt;//adds numbers together
            dgt = carry / 10;
            carry = carry % 10;
            i1--;
            i2--;
            sb.append((char) ('0' + carry));
        }
        while (i1 >= 0) {
            carry = this.digit[i1] + dgt;
            dgt = carry / 10;
            carry = carry % 10;
            i1--;
            sb.append((char) ('0' + carry));
        }
        while (i2 >= 0) {
            carry = d.digit[i2] + dgt;
            dgt = carry / 10;
            carry = carry % 10;
            i2--;
            sb.append((char) ('0' + carry));
        }
        sb = sb.reverse();
        return new BigStringNumber(sb.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigStringNumber a = new BigStringNumber("2020202029");
        BigStringNumber b = new BigStringNumber("4040404046");
        System.out.println(a.add(b).toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Created by SidMore on 5/6/2016.
 */
public class AddLargeString {

    private String s1;
    private String s2;

    public AddLargeString(String s1, String s2){
        this.s1 = new StringBuilder(s1).reverse().toString();
        this.s2 = new StringBuilder(s2).reverse().toString();
    }

    public String add() {

        int[] d = new int[s1.length() + 1];

        if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
                d[i] = s1.charAt(i) - '0';
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
                d[j] = d[j] + s2.charAt(j) - '0';
            }
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
                d[i] = s1.charAt(i) - '0';
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++) {
                d[j] = d[j] + s1.charAt(j) - '0';
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            int mod = d[i] % 10;
            int carry = d[i] / 10;
            if (i + 1 < d.length)
                d[i + 1] += carry;
            sb.insert(0, mod);
        }

        //remove front 0's
        while (sb.charAt(0) == '0' && sb.length() > 1) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(0);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       AddLargeString aLS = new AddLargeString("3560","9");
       System.out.println("Addition: " + aLS.add());
   }
}
```