# Sum of any digits of numbers

Tags: java, operators

I think this one is easy ques,but I want to know how to sum any no of digits in java.

There is specific range of datatype if we add any no to its `MAX_VALUE`, it prints the -ve no.

e.g `12344587387873878 + 374892 = ?`

Any logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BigInteger` for this.

Look at the `BigInteger` class.

Additionally you can implement that yourself.

See here:

[How would i add very large Numbers represented as Strings i.e 50 digit numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682549/how-would-i-add-very-large-numbers-represented-as-strings-i-e-50-digit-numbers)

Comment: OP needs the logic behind it.

Comment: The logic is to do it as in 1st or 2nd grade. Start backwards, work through the numbers, and add digit by digit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store ***any*** number (*technically your example could be a long*) you will want to use `BigDecimal`. `BigInteger` can also be used if you know that your sum will be a whole number.

`BigDecimal` Example;

```
BigDecimal bigD1 = new BigDecimal(1234458738787.387*1000);
BigDecimal bigD2 = new BigDecimal(374892.5);
System.out.println(bigD1.add(bigD2));
```

Output: **1234458739162279.5**.

As `12344587387873878` is too big to store as an integer you can't just type it in as a literal (all non-floating point literals are implicitly ints) to go into your `BigDecimal` constructor. So I divided it by 1000 myself, and then `*1000` in the constructor. Alternatively you could use scientific notation.

***OR***, you can pass BigDecimal a string.

```
BigDecimal bigD1 = new BigDecimal("1234458738787387");
```

As a warning, BigDecimal does have it's issues with very high accuracy numbers. It can not accurately represent Pi, or even 1/3rd for example.